# solubility trends of alkaline earth metals

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

Why is the solubility trend of group 2 oxalate compounds inconsistent with the actual order in the periodic table?

Comment: Related: [What is the order of solubility of oxalates in group 2 (alkaline earth metals)?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/40704/7951)

Comment: Because the periodic table has many such apparent oddities. Such oddities are our fault of trying to impose strict simple rules on a messy universe.